# Finding the Sum of all records with group by

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, aggregate

I am building SQL Query
This query has to show top Paid vendors and the details of the payments for each vendor per month, and at the same time the total payments for the vendor

```
VendorTable
Vendor varchar(100)
PayDate Date
Amt int
```

-

```
Vendor   PayDate    Amt
Vendor1  01-Jan-15  $70
Vendor1  13-Jan-15  $30
Vendor2  04-Mar-16  $180
Vendor2  21-Mar-16  $70
Vendor3  17-Sep-16  $300
```

Example of the end result

```
Vendor   Month   MonthlyAmt   TotalAmt
Vendor1  Jan-15  $100         $870
Vendor2  Mar-16  $250         $900
Vendor3  Sep-16  $300         $720
Vendor1  Dec-16  $140         $870
Vendor2  Feb-17  $210         $900
Vendor1  Apr-17  $400         $870
Vendor3  Aug-17  $420         $900
Vendor2  Nov-17  $330         $900
Vendor2  Mar-18  $110         $900
Vendor1  May-18  $230         $870
```

My SELECT looks like this

```
SELECT TOP 10 Vendor, Month(PayDate) + '-' + Year(PayDate), SUM(Amt), ????????
FROM VendorsTable
GROUP BY Vendor, Month(PayDate) + '-' + Year(PayDate)
ORDER BY ???????? DESC
```

not sure how to find the total for all payments for the vendor

Comment: please explain how the totalAmount column is calculated.?

Comment: its the sum of all months for that vendor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT t1.vendor, 
       Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), t1.paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-') AS PayDate, 
       Sum(t1.amt)                                                      AS MonthlyAmt, 
       Max(t2.totalamt)                                                 AS TotalAmt 
FROM   tablename t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT vendor, Sum(amt) AS TotalAmt 
                   FROM   tablename 
                   GROUP  BY vendor) t2 
               ON t1.vendor = t2.vendor 
GROUP  BY t1.vendor, Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), t1.paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-')
```

Output
Please note that these sample data varies from your data

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| vendor  | PayDate | MonthlyAmt | TotalAmt |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| Vendor1 | Jan-15  |        100 |      110 |
| Vendor1 | Jan-16  |         10 |      110 |
| Vendor2 | Mar-16  |        250 |      250 |
| Vendor3 | Sep-16  |        300 |      300 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Top 10 Vendors & Months

```
SELECT TOP 10 t1.vendor, 
              Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), t1.paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-') AS PayDate, 
              Sum(t1.amt) AS MonthlyAmt, 
              Max(t2.totalamt) AS TotalAmt 
FROM   tablename t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT vendor, Sum(amt) AS TotalAmt 
                   FROM   tablename 
                   GROUP  BY vendor) t2 
               ON t1.vendor = t2.vendor 
GROUP  BY t1.vendor, Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), t1.paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-') 
ORDER  BY monthlyamt DESC
```

Output

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| vendor  | PayDate | MonthlyAmt | TotalAmt |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| Vendor3 | Sep-16  |        300 |      300 |
| Vendor2 | Mar-16  |        250 |      250 |
| Vendor1 | Jan-15  |        100 |      110 |
| Vendor1 | Jan-16  |         10 |      110 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
```

---

<sup>Reference</sup>
  <sup>- http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems the the ROLLUP option is what you need:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Vendor, Month(PayDate) + '-' + Year(PayDate), SUM(Amt), ????????
FROM VendorsTable
GROUP BY Vendor, Month(PayDate) + '-' + Year(PayDate)
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY ???????? DESC
```

You will get one additional row for each Vendor and Date, with the total for each of them, plus a total with the sum of everything

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Ok, discard my previous answer, I didn't realize that the table you have shown in your post was the result and not the original data. This means that you have to use a Window Function to solve your problem:

```
with samplevalues as
(
select
    *
from
    (values 
        ('Vendor1', 'Jan-15', 100, 870),
        ('Vendor2', 'Mar-16', 250,  900),
        ('Vendor3', 'Sep-16',   300, 720),
        ('Vendor1', 'Dec-16',   140, 870),
        ('Vendor2', 'Feb-17',   210, 900),
        ('Vendor1', 'Apr-17',   400, 870),
        ('Vendor3', 'Aug-17',   420, 900),
        ('Vendor2', 'Nov-17',   330, 900),
        ('Vendor2', 'Mar-18',   110, 900),
        ('Vendor1', 'May-18 ',  230, $870)
    ) T(Vendor, [Month], MonthlyAmt, TotalAmt)
)
select
    Vendor, [Month], SUM(MonthlyAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY Vendor)
from
    samplevalues
```

that should do exactly what you need.

More info or the OVER clause here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

is this helpful.?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Vendor
      ,Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-') AS Month
      ,SUM(Amt) OVER(Partition by Vendor,Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-')) As MonthlyAmt,
       SUM(Amt) OVER(Partition by Vendor) AS TotalAmt
FROM VendorTable
```

With order by clause:

```
;with cte
 AS
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT Vendor,Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-') AS Month
     ,SUM(Amt) OVER(Partition by Vendor,Replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9), paydate, 6), 6), ' ', '-')) As MonthlyAmt,
     SUM(Amt) OVER(Partition by Vendor) AS TotalAmt
  FROM VendorTable   
 )

 select Vendor,Month,MonthlyAmt,TotalAmt
 FROM cte 
 ORDER BY CAST('20'+SUBSTRING(Month,5,2) + '-' +SUBSTRING(Month,0,4) + '-' + '01' AS DATE)
```

SQL Fiddle Link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26ef4/99/0